# Show that $x^4+1$ is reducible in p-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for p>2 prime.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

This is a homework problem for algebraic number theory but I'm having trouble getting started. Do I use induction in general, or show this holds for $p \equiv 1,3$ (mod 4)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: do you have a square root of 2 available? [Clearly you are done if you have a fourth root of -1 to hand]

Comment: Mark's hint is on exactly the right path, but it's worth asking: what would make you even think to use induction on this problem?  What would you induct over?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think he wants to use Newton approximation / Hensel lemma, i.e.  stepping from $\mod p^n$ to $\mod p^{n+1}$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Ahhh, okay, that makes a lot more sense.  I'd been thinking about stepping from one prime to the next, which seemed crazy on the face of it.

Answer (score 6):

(1) Use the fact that
$$X^4+1 = (X^2+\sqrt{-1})(X^2-\sqrt{-1}) = (X^2+\sqrt{2}X+1)(X^2-\sqrt{2}X+1) = (X^2+\sqrt{-2}X-1)(X^2-\sqrt{-2}X-1),$$
to show that $X^4+1$ is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ (even for $p=2$). You may need the law of quadratic reciprocity.

(2) Conclude with Hensel Lemma.